# Magento 1.9.1.0 Order Confirmation Emails - Not Sending

Tags: magento

I've recently upgraded to Magento CE 1.9.1.0 and our order confirmation emails are not being sent to customers or the employees here that are setup to receive notifications.

I checked the Email Logs and don't see the emails hitting the server at all.

Emails come through from the Contact Form, New User Account Signup and a few test scripts I created on the server.  I made sure that Disable Email Communications was set to "No".

Any ideas?  They worked great in 1.7.0.2 before we upgraded.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post it on the Stack Overflow sister-site https://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting from *Magento 1.9* the order confirmation emails are not sent during *checkout* anymore, instead they are sent with the **Cron**. To verify this works properly:

- make sure your system Cron is up and running (you can check the Cron logs: `/var/log/cron` to verify that).
- make sure Magento Cron is setup correctly and is running every some minutes. You should see something like this in the Crontab of your system:

  `*/5 * * * * /public_html/cron.sh`

  This schedules a task to run `cron.sh` every five minute. ([More reading](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron))

There are good extensions like [AOE Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) in Magento that help you to monitor and manage Cron jobs.

---

An alternative way to this is to *disable* the Cron for these kind of emails (*order confirmation*). To do this you can go to this path:

```
public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Copy that file and bring it to this path (if the path doesn't exist create it):

```
public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

And then change this line:

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

To:

```
$mailer->send();
```

However I recommend spending some time to setup the Cron instead. I think if they wanted to use Cron for these emails it's for a reason.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  The cron was indeed not setup properly.  I did have to add "$isShellDisabled = true;" to the cron.php file as it appears to be a bug.  Found that tip on another site.

Comment: Late to the party, but hey, this is _exactly_ how to degrade the project in terms of maintainability. No serious other software framework would encourage this way of overwriting core functionality. Think of what happens when this file changes in a new release..

Comment: Since Magento 1.9 isn't updated anymore and this error still occurs sporadically in legacy systems, it can be a viable fix if nothing else works.

Answer (score 14):

Just do a small change in order.php (`public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`)

From

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

To

```
$mailer->send();
```

Comment: THANKS, been trying to resolve this issue for days now.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is simple that i found.

```
go to System -> Configuration -> ASCHRODER EXTENSIONS -> SMTP -> Queue Configuration -> Queue Usage -> Never
```

Done!

Order Confirmation will be sent quickly. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Quick solution is:**

Go to the following location: `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

Change Line 407

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

To:

```
if (!($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue)) {
```

It will work.

Thanks Pankaj

Comment: doing this threw a fatal error at me regarding line 410

Answer (score 1):

Please ovewrite 'app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php' file.if you dont want to any changes in xml file so So just copy /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php into /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php and be sure to refresh the cache. and change

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

To

```
$mailer->send();
```

Comment: never overwrite core files

Answer (score 1):

Goto /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php

Below changes :

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

To

```
if (false){
```

Comment: typo: `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. For me it was a local copy of the order.php that I had made some changes to in the past and that I had copied to \app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php.

Thus, the updated order.php of Magento 1.9.1.0 in the core directory was not in usage - causing the order confirmation emails not to be send automatically via the cron job.

I keep the fingers crossed that you suffer from the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add cron in cpanel or plesk panel. It will available on cpanel -> Advanced and click cron folder. Then proceed:

- `*/5` in the 'minute' field (may customize this)
- `*` in the 'hour' field
- `*` in the 'day' field
- `*` in the 'month' field
- `*` in the 'weekday' field

comment: http://www.yoursite.com/absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers  but none worked for me. How i solved is that, 
check that if your default template setup are  there in the magento or not. Sometimes during installation its lost and actually "there is no email template by default in system to send your email". Please go to Admin side,  `System->Transactional Email->` by default you will find no template here. So add one by clicking on button '`Add new Email template`. In `Load default template`  panel select a template from the Template drop down suppose forgot Password and click  and click `Load Template`.   As earlier said no email template is associated with it so it will not be show in below.   The bset thing is to go to install a fresh copy of magento in your local system navigate here and put that same content here and click Save Template button.
Then go to `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration ->Password Options->Change` the 'Forgot Email Template' dropdown   to yours as added above .Happy . thus same thing you can also do for order ,shipment, new account etc.

Answer (score 0):

To debug magento order mail issue regarding new order just run yoursite.com/cron.php
If you recieve any mail now then its cron issue.
You can fix con issue by setting cron in cpanel.