# Why arent my sales emails sending?

Tags: magento

All I have a fully working magento store but i'm having issues, when a customer purchases something they're not getting an email confirmation and I dont know why, everything is set up correctly, we receive emails when a customer submits items they want samples of they come through fine, even when you goto the backend and view the invoice and select send email invoice they don't get an email, I have no idea why this isn't working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using paypal payments pro as a payment method.

Comment: What Magento version are you on?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending/27458300#27458300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Magento 1.9+ send transactional emails as "background process" using the Magento crontab system. If you haven't already setup cron for your Magento store then you need to setup now for sending emails.

You can checkout this guide on how to setup the Magento cronjob -

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-cron

OR

Follow the steps below to setup cron job -

First of all make sure you have set up cron tasks in the `

> Magento admin under System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron

The default settings are:

```
Generate Schedules Every 15
Schedule Ahead for 20
Missed if Not Run Within 15
History Cleanup Every 10
Success History Lifetime 60
Failure History Lifetime 600
```

You then need to go into your hosting control panel and set up cron jobs. In cPanel it’s under `Advanced > Cron Jobs`. Set them up to run every five minutes and use this command:

> php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php

Check that the above path is correct and that the file cron.php is actually there in the root of your Magento installation.

If this is not the case, you can check the database table: `core_email_queue`

The emails that should have been send should be in this queue, if not you should check your system configuration again, and maybe check on the store view your orders are from, to make sure the setting is not different under specific store view.

If the emails are there and have a date in the column processed at. You should check your Servers email log, since the receiver might be rejecting your emails, If its on a linux machine, its usually found in `/var/log/mail.log`

We have written a blog post here explaining how to [setup CRON in Magento](http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-magento-magento-cron-tutorial/), i think this might explain in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things this could be, but if the other emails are working it sounds like a config issue, so check this.

In admin, take a look in

```
System > Configuration (TOP MENU)
```

Then;

```
Sales Emails (LEFT MENU),
```

Check which contact is sending the email - eg Sales Rep.  While you're here, add your personal email to the 'Send Order Copy To' field for testing - make sure it's not the same domain as the website, so like a gmail.com address or similar.  Also check what email template is set and make sure it exists.  If 'default from locale', check;

```
app/locale/[DEFAULT COUNTRY CODE]/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html
app/locale/[DEFAULT COUNTRY CODE]/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

Now go and check the email address set for the sender (New Order Confirmation Email Sender) - eg Sales Rep, these are in;

```
Store Email Address (LEFT MENU)
```

Ensure there is a value for email address and name, and it is correct.  If it is, go and place an order using another personal email address at a different domain like gmail etc (not the same email address you set for the copy).

Hopefully the emails you do or dont recieve now will help you corectly trace the issue.

EXTRA

If you still receive no emails, couple of things to look at;

Check System > Config > Advanced and make sure smtp isnt disabled (seems unlikely as your other emails are sending)

Make sure paypal pro is setting the status to processed

Try changing the email address being used to send them, eg Sales
 rep.  Try changing this to an email address with a different domain,
 such as gmail.com etc.  If this works, then you need to look at how
 your domain and email has been setup on the server.

Check your error logs /var/logs/

Comment: Cheers for the instructions but it didn't work, is it because of my payment method??

Comment: No i dont think so. Sounds like you are making it to the order success page after ordering - and the order is placed in the backend.  Try adding a note to the order in admin, put a tick in the 'Notify customer by email' box before saving the comment.  Does that make it through?

Comment: Oh Yeh I tried that I tried sending a message to the customer, an clicking notify the customer but still it wont send anything.

Comment: Well it was processing but I refunded it as it was a test purchase and it went through processing to refunded, so the connection to paypal is setup but at anytime during the order it never sent anything to the customer.

Comment: added a couple of other things to look at

Comment: My logs say nothing regarding an order, changed the email address that a sales order comes from that didnt work, tried notifying the user through the order page that didn't work, really annoying !!