# Order confirmation email not sending to customer?

Tags: email, magento

I am using `magento 1.9.1 version` . After place successful order email not sending to customer.

```
if (false/\*$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue\*/) {

 /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
        $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
        $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
        'subject'  => $subject,
                'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                'reply_to' => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                'return_to'=> $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
            ))
            ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
            ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
        $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();
      $order->getSendConfirmation(null);
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
        return true;
    }` `
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your cron running? 
Magento is queuing this mails and the cron sends these mails since 1.9.1. This is done so that order placing goes faster since it doesn't need to wait on the mail sending.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458300/3992313

Comment: Cron, this is a periodic task your server should run every 5 minutes. Please see this same question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458300/3992313

In that question is explained how to install the cron. To confirm that this is the problem you could also manually run cron.php or cron.sh 2 times.