# Magento cron.php appears to be running hundreds of times

Tags: php, email, magento, cron

To test my cron I placed a simple `mail()` call in the head of cron.php.
I set up the cron to run every 5 minutes and so I was expecting to receive 1 email every 5 minutes.
However I received hundreds of emails when it runs (300+).

I'm running Magento 1.9.1.0 and on previous versions this never happened (just 1 email each time the cron ran)

cron is setup through cPanel: `*/5 * * * *` and I'm confident not running multiple times itself. (I have tested with a simple php file with 1 mail call)

Anyone seen this before? Obviously the easiest fix would be to remove the mail call but I'm just worried that cron.php is being called so much and will effect the server.

Comment: actually the only big difference (from the Cron point of view) in new Magento versions is that they are using Cron more than before (including transactional+order confirmations):  [1](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458300/2568469)