# Magento Cron Setup Correct

Tags: php, magento, plugins, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have been trying to setup a cron job in Magento. I have been reading and followed the tutorials for a few. Now i do not understand what needs to be done to setup a cron job. I followed this tutorial http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/  however it did not work I tried a few others but they were no good either. Based on the reading on stackoverflow people seemed to use MAGE? to link to cron jobs however they are not clearly explaining how. I can not seem to understand what i need to add to make this work. Any suggestions

```
<crontab>
        <jobs>
            <customconfig>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>customconfig/observer::cronEvent</model></run>
            </customconfig>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Comment: Please make sure your Magento Cron is set up correctly. I had a relevant and more descriptive answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458300/2568469).

Comment: there is no folder called cron in the log folder. the log folder is empty @Hatef

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows @Hatef

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the replies in comment section I suppose using *Windows* you don't have any system Cron that is runing Magento Cron. In such case you could force running Magento Cron using PHP; Try something like this:

```
path/to/php.exe path/to/magento-folder/cron.php
```

It should run your Magento Cron (only once) and schedule the tasks. You could track scheduled tasks in Magento Database table which is called `cron_schedule`. You might need to force cron.php several times (let's say every 1-2 minutes) to see whether your cronjobs are schedule or not.

Comment: i do not understand what to do with this path/to/php.exe path/to/magento-folder/cron.php

Comment: It means you should run `cron.php` file using PHP (`php.exe`).. You can find `php.exe` where your PHP is installed. Are you using `XAMPP` or something similar? (if so it's under \XAMPP\php\); And `cron.php` is located where your Magento is installed.. you can find it in Magento's root directory..

Comment: its on a linux server. centos? sorry only found out now

Comment: Make sure your system's Cron is running Magento's cron correctly. Do you see something like this in your crontab? `*/5 * * * * /public_html/cron.sh` (using this in command-line: `crontab -l`)

Comment: how do i do that when i go on putty i type in the command and it says no cron for root?

Comment: Seems like your Cron has some issues. Follow this reply [here](http://serverfault.com/a/449652/197515) to see if you can fix your Cron issues.